# Spring boot JPA Как получить последнюю запись из базы данных

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Spring boot. Jpa.

**model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="weather")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"createdAt"}, allowGetters = true)
public class Weather implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;

    @NotBlank
    private String cityName;

    @Lob
    private String openWeatherData;

    @Lob
    private String weatherStackData;
```

В поля **openWeatherData** и **weatherStackData** записываю JSON  в строковом виде.

В проекте используется JPA.

**WeatherRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface WeatherRepository extends JpaRepository<Weather, Long> {

   Weather findFirstByOrderByCreatedAtDesc();

}
```

Пытаюсь написать свой query запрос в бд., типа этого.

**Controller**

```
@GetMapping("/openWeather")
  public JSONObject getOpenWeatherData() throws ParseException {
  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
  String weather = weatherRepository.findFirstByOrderByCreatedAtDesc().getOpenWeatherData();
   return (JSONObject) parser.parse(weather);
}
```

В контроллере получаю json в строковом виде из базы, преобразую в JSON формат, отправляю ....
Вылетает ошибка:

> "Unable to access lob stream; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream"

Джависты выручайте. Это мое тестовое задание. Край как нужно сделать.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что выхотите поднять из БД два самых больших поля из пяти? Какой в этом смысл? Чем вас не устраивает сущность целиком. Поднять, конечно, можно - создаете отдельный класс с этими полями. И потом в репозитории пишите запрос который должен вернуть вам этот объект. Но в данном случае, на мой взгляд, это не оправданно.

Comment: Хорошо, подскажете как взять из бд, последнюю запись целиком(т.е. со всеми полями). И как потом разделить эти поля? (т.е. отдельно id, createdAt, cityName, и тд)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Последнюю запись можете получить так

```
 @Repository
 public interface WeatherRepository extends JpaRepository<Weather, Long> {

     Weather findFirstByOrderByCreatedAtDesc();

 }
```

Comment: Спасибо за участие. Я получаю данный объект из базы, а как мне его дальше разобрать на части. Что с этим вообще можно сделать? Я в тупике...

Comment: Вы получаете объект Weather, в нем у вас должны быть get/set методы, просто вызываете метод getОpenWeatherData() и получаете свою строку json. Дальше работаете с ней как вам надо. А спасибо здесь принято говорить принятием ответа и голосованием стрелками слева от ответа

Comment: Подскажите как справиться с ошибкой  **Unable to access lob stream; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to access lob stream"**